# PHP Search Get Text Before / After

Tags: php, mysql

How would I go about turning my search results into something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfPGs.png

Where the results show where in the cell the particular term is.

I currently have this basic search script:

```
      $terms = explode("-", $SQuery);
    $QuerySQL = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE ";

        foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;

        if ($i == 1)
            $QuerySQL .= "Title LIKE '%$each%' OR Content LIKE '%$each%' OR Description LIKE '%$each%'";
        else 
            $QuerySQL .= "OR Title LIKE '%$each%' OR Description LIKE '%$each%' OR Content LIKE '%$each%'";
        }

    $QueryNEW = mysql_query($QuerySQL);

WHILE($datarows_cat = mysql_fetch_array($QueryNEW)):

        $title = $datarows_cat['Title'];
        $Deleted = $datarows_cat['Deleted'];
        $id = $datarows_cat['ID'];
        if ($Deleted != "YES") {
        echo "<a href='/{$id}'>{$title}</a><br/>";

}
```

Comment: I really don't know what to try. What would I use to do this?

Comment: You are using a deprecated API (ext/mysql). Use MySQLi/PDO for new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PHP strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find +/- 100 characters:

```
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Then use [PHP substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the substring of `$pos+100` and `$pos-100`

```
//For instance your substring could start at the position of the word found minus 100 characters and a length of 200
$result = substr($mystring, $pos-100, 200);
```

You can use [PHP str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to format the string you need:

```
$word_your_looking_for = "test";
$word_you_want_to_replace_it_with = "<b>test</b>"; //Make it bold

str_replace($word_your_looking_for, $word_you_want_to_replace_it_with, $your_string);
```

Comment: But then how would I get say 100 characters before & after that word?